# How to find range from the graph using MAPLE?

Tags: maple

[image]

I want to find the range of h for n=1, n=2 and n=3 using Maple from this graph. But I do not know how to find it. Can someone help me?

Comment: You want to have Maple look at the graph and tell you the range of $h$?

Comment: Yes, and btw I obtained this graph after solved the equation using Maple. Now I just want to know value of the range of h.

Comment: Do you have the actual graph data structure, or just the picture?

Comment: Or better yet, the commands and data structures you used to create the graph.

Answer (score 0):

The graph data structure will have several CURVES structures, one for each curve.  Each typically has as its first entry a Matrix whose rows are the data points.  Thus if P is the plot,

```
indets(P, Matrix);
```

will give you a set of three matrices.  The first column gives the $x$ values, the second the $y$ values, for the points of the curve.  Caution: if a `view` option was used in the plot command, not all points in the Matrix will be shown.